# Assigning a view to a specific record type

Tags: record-type, custom-view

I want to have 2 different record types for my Account object. Say 'A' and 'B'.
They are related to each other i.e. my Account objects have many-to-many relationship.
I want to create a view say 'All B Accounts' which displays all B accounts for an A account and hence the view should only be available to select for an A type account.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get you right, but what you are looking for sounds more like a related list to me, which shows all B Accounts for a given A.

This would be pretty much standard functionality available in the wizard where you define the relation (Lookup or Mastet/Detail) or later on if you edit the layout and select related lists. But I wonder if this is really what you're looking for. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Uwe Heim,Yes I know I can use related list, but the customer wants to see this as a seperate view like the views available - "All Accounts", "My Accounts". This one can be named as "All B Accounts" and should be available only for type A accounts. Is that possible in Salesforce?

Comment: Due to my knowledge it can't be done this way. So if no one else tells us better, you should stick with the related list, which comes pretty close to the stated requirements.